# AngularJS set routes in App.config function conditionally

Tags: angularjs

I have a following ambiguity with AngularJS config function. 
It seems that config function is synchronous. I want to request 
one backend service and construct routing according to its response. 
When I remove request and $q everything working properly.

```
someApp.config(['$routeProvider', '$httpProvider', '$compileProvider', 'settings',
    function ($routeProvider, $httpProvider, $compileProvider, settings) {

        var $http = angular.injector(['ng']).get('$http');
        var $q = angular.injector(['ng']).get('$q');
        var isUserLogged = $q.defer();

        $http.get(settings.apiUri + settings.loginStatus).success(function (data) {
            if (data.status == "NOT_LOGGED") {
                isUserLogged.reject();
            } else {
                isUserLogged.resolve();
            }
        });

        isUserLogged.promise.catch(function () {
             $routeProvider.
                 when('/home', {
                     templateUrl: 'partials/home.html',
                     controller: 'HomeController'
                 }).
                 otherwise({
                 redirectTo: '/home'
             });
        });

        isUserLogged.promise.then(function () {
            $routeProvider.
                when('/accountsettings', {
                    templateUrl: 'partials/accountsettings.html',
                    controller: 'AccountSettingsController'
                }).
                otherwise({
                    redirectTo: '/accountsettings'
                });
        });
    }]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently I have to answer myself. First I make request to determine whether the user is logged or not. Then I trigger custom event listener whose call .config method of application and do routing in accordance whether the user is logged or not. Below is the code of the decision to which I got (with abbreviations). [Here](http://georgi-naumov.blogspot.com/2014/08/dynamic-routing-in-angularjs-appconfig.html) is  link to my blog where I wrote more on the subject.

```
angular.element(document).one("userStatusIsCheked", 
                        function(event, userIsLogged) {
    appName.config(['$routeProvider', 
        '$httpProvider', '$compileProvider',
        function ($routeProvider, 
         $httpProvider, $compileProvider) {
            if (userIsLogged == true) {
                $routeProvider.
                    when('/resetpassword/:hashValue', {
                        templateUrl: 'partials/home.html',
                        controller: 'ResetPasswordController'
                    }).
                    when('/accountsettings', {
                        templateUrl: 'partials/accountsettings.html',
                        controller: 'AccountSettingsController'
                    }).
                    when('/changepassword', 
                      {
                        templateUrl: 
                        'partials/accountsettingschangepassword.html',
                        controller: 'ChangePasswordController'
                    }).
                    when('/edit', {
                        templateUrl: 'partials/accountsettingsedit.html',
                        controller: 'EditAccountController'
                    }).
                    when('/apikeymanagement', {
                        templateUrl: 'partials/apikeymanagement.html',
                        controller: 'APIKeyManagementController'
                    }).
                    when('/dashboard', {
                        templateUrl: 'partials/dashboard.html',
                        controller: 'DashboardController'
                    }).
                    when('/pipelines', {
                        templateUrl: 'partials/pipelines.html',
                        controller: 'PipeLinesController'
                    }).
                    when('/preferences', {
                        templateUrl: 'partials/preferences.html',
                        controller: 'PreferencesController'
                    }).
                    when('/reports', {
                        templateUrl: 'partials/reports.html',
                        controller: 'ReportsController'
                    }).
                    when('/logout', {
                        templateUrl: 'partials/logout.html',
                        controller: 'LogoutController',
                        resolve: {
                            logout: function (logout, $q) {
                                var deferred = $q.defer();
                                logout()['finally'](
                                    function() {
                                        deferred.resolve();
                                    }
                                );
                                return deferred.promise;
                            }
                        }
                    }).
                    when('/privacy', {
                        templateUrl: 'partials/privacy.html',
                        controller: 'PrivacyController'
                    }).
                    when('/tos', {
                        templateUrl: 'partials/tos.html',
                        controller: 'TosController'
                    }).
                    when('/currentStatus', {
                        templateUrl: 'partials/currentStatus.html',
                        controller: 'CurrentStatusController'
                    }).
                    otherwise({
                        redirectTo: '/dashboard'
                    });

            } else {
                /**
                 * If user is not logged default action is
                 * home.
                 */
                $routeProvider.
                    when('/home', {
                        templateUrl: 'partials/home.html',
                        controller: 'HomeController'
                    }).
                    when('/resetpassword/:hashValue', {
                        templateUrl: 'partials/home.html',
                        controller: 'ResetPasswordController'
                    }).
                    when('/privacy', {
                        templateUrl: 'partials/privacy.html',
                        controller: 'PrivacyController'
                    }).
                    when('/tos', {
                        templateUrl: 'partials/tos.html',
                        controller: 'TosController'
                    }).
                    when('/currentStatus', {
                        templateUrl: 'partials/currentStatus.html',
                        controller: 'CurrentStatusController'
                    }).
                    otherwise({
                        redirectTo: '/home'
                    });

            }
        }]);

        angular.bootstrap(document, ['appName']);
});

angular.element(document).ready(function() {
    var injector = angular.injector(['appName']);
    var settings = injector.get('settings');
    var $http = injector.get('$http');

    var functionFactory = function (userStatus) {
        return function () {
            this.lUserStatus = userStatus;
            return this.lUserStatus;
        }
    };

    /**
     * So here we will check if user is logged or
     * not and after this construct conditional routing
     * into config method (above).
     */
    $http.get(settings.apiUri + settings.loginStatus).
             success(function (data) {
        if(angular.isDefined(data.status) && 
            data.status == "NOT_AUTHENTICATED") {
            appName.service('userIsLogged', functionFactory(false));
            angular.element(document).trigger("userStatusIsCheked", [false]);
        } else if(angular.isDefined(data.status) && data.
                status == "AUTHENTICATED") {
            appName.service('userIsLogged', 
            functionFactory(true));
            angular.element(document).trigger("userStatusIsCheked", [true]);
        }
    });
});
```